# Inject second array randomly inside the first

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, one used do display images and the other one for ads:

```
$ads = Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [description] => Long Ad
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [description] => Tower Ad
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [description] => Small Ad
        )

)

$images = Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => My House
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => Forest Panorama
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => Dog Picture
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => Sunset
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => Sunrise
        )

)
```

I have tried using the following code:

```
foreach ($images as $i=> $row) {
    $offset = array_rand($images);
    array_splice($images, $offset, 0, $ads);
    print $row->description . "<br>";

}
```

In the above I only get three records instead of 8 in total. I would like to insert $ads array inside the loop randomly. Order of $images array must remain the same, while $ads array is injected at random places.

Comment: `$mergedArray = array_merge($images, $ads); shuffle($mergedArray);`

Comment: So you just want to randomize the `$ads` array and then merge it together with the `$images` array, right?

Comment: Try: `shuffle($ads);
  print_r(array_merge($images, $ads));` Does that do the trick for you? OR do you also want the elements from `$ads` also between the `$images` elements ?

Comment: @Rizier123 I want $ads array to be randomly injected within $images array, while preserving an order of $images array. shuffle() in this case will not help.

Comment: @Alko Ok so you also want elements from `$ads` between `$images` elements. But you want to keep the order of `$images`. So do you always want to inject 1 random element between `$images` elements OR sometimes 2 or 3 ?

Comment: yes one element from $ads, could be every 2nd, 3rd or 10th element it does not matter as long as it's randomly placed.

Comment: And always 1 random element never like 2 random elements at once?

Comment: that's correct, just one $ad element, lets say after every 5th or 7th $image element.

Comment: @Alko And lets say both arrays have 4 elements. If you now don't add an element from `$ads` to `$images` on the 2 element, what should it do with the element? delete it? append it at the end? overwrite the first one?

Comment: I'm always going to have more images than ads. Images must remain no matter what, and I dont want to jam all ads towards the end of an array.

Comment: @Alko So it could be that you don't add all ads to the images, right?

Comment: @Alko Last thing then I think we figured all out: Can an element from ads also be injected multiple times to images?

Comment: yes, they can as long as they are not being repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally, I think this is what you want and it should work for you:

```
<?php

    $tmp = $ads;

    foreach($images as $v) {
        if(rand(1, 100) >= 40) { //To 60%(100-40) percent an ads element gets injected 
            $key = array_rand($tmp, 1);
            $v->description = $ads[$key]->description;
            unset($tmp[$key]);
        }
    }

?>
```

To display the data use:

```
foreach($images as $image) {
    echo "image: " . $image->title . (isset($image->description)?(" | description: " . $image->description . "<br>"):"<br>");
}
```

example output:

```
image: Dog picture | description: Small Ad
image: Sunset
image: Sunrise | description: Long Ad
```

Comment: I'm getting few errors " Warning: array_rand(): Second argument has to be between 1 and the number of elements in the array2"

Comment: @Alko Your `$ads` array is smaller than the `$images` array right? Post like a pastebin how you use my code in your script. Code works fine for me: http://3v4l.org/cb44r

Comment: Yes,  ads array is smaller than images, and I'm using it exactly the same code as you have provided, but the error comes randomly, not all the time.

Comment: @Alko Try to use this if statement: `if(rand(1, 100) >= 40 && count($tmp) > 0) {` does that do the trick?